# Is my approach correct in evaluating this limit: $\lim_{A\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\lVert f(\mathbf{x})\rVert}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to understand whether the following argument is correct or wrong.

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(\mathbf{x})=\exp(-\mathbf{x}^\top A\mathbf{x}) A\mathbf{x}$, where $A=\operatorname{diag}\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right)\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

I'm interested in finding the limit of $\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\lVert f(\mathbf{x})\rVert}$ as $A\to\mathbf{0}_n$, and towards this I though that I could take $A=aI_n$ with $a\to0^+$ so as
$$
\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\lVert f(\mathbf{x})\rVert}
=
\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{\exp(-\mathbf{x}^\top A\mathbf{x}) A\mathbf{x}}{\lVert \exp(-\mathbf{x}^\top A\mathbf{x}) A\mathbf{x} \rVert}
=
\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{A\mathbf{x}}{\lVert A\mathbf{x}\rVert}
=
\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{a\mathbf{x}}{\lVert a\mathbf{x}\rVert}
=
\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert}.
$$

Have I missed any tricky part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it depends on how you approach $\mathbf 0_n$. The first two equalities are true in general, and
$$\frac{(Ax)_i}{\|Ax\|} = \frac{  x_i}{\sqrt{\sum_j a_i^{-2}a_j^2 x_j^2}}$$
So, here's a simple counterexample; consider $n=2$ and $A_n = \operatorname{diag}(1/n, 2/n) \to 0$. Then
$$ \frac{(A_nx)_1}{\|A_nx\|} = \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + 4x_2^2}}, \quad \frac{(A_nx)_2}{\|A_nx\|} = \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2/4 + x_2^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand. Do you think there are any conditions for approaching $\mathbf{0}_n$ that could guarantee the existence of the limit?

Comment: @nullgeppetto you're welcome. The only time I can see it having a limit is if. you pick a specific path (e.g. $aI$, $a \operatorname{diag}(1,2)$, etc)

Comment: So, if I let it be $A=aI_n$ and approach $a\to0_+$ the limit exists, right? Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes @nullgeppetto. Glad to help!